# Search product work wrong in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

i have a problem with searching products in Magento 2.

Ex : My store have 2 products, ABC and XYZ. When I search for the keyword "ABC" or "XYZ", it show product ABC or XYZ. But if i search for keyword "123", it show many product, it not show message empty `We can't find products matching the selection.` in list.phtml

Why does it display those products while the keyword i entered doesn't have anything to do with it? Please help me, thanks all.